# Divide by 0 on purpose

Tags: trigonometry

Many times when I solve equations (particularly trigonometric equations) I try to use trigonometric identities, factories etc. to simplify my problem. But when the opportunity is given I find it easy to divide and add one equation.

Easy example:  $\sin x = \cos x$

Divide by $\cos x$ and add the equation $\cos x=0$ in case it might be equal to zero.

Is this **in general** an acceptable method for solving equations?

Comment: By any chance, did you mean $\cos x\neq 0$?

Comment: A side-note: What do you mean by "factories"?

Comment: I believe OP means "factors".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That doesn't work in this case: if $\cos x = 0$ then $\sin x \ne 0$, so the equation $\cos x = 0$ doesn't yield any solutions to the equation $\sin x = \cos x$.

But you might be working along the right lines. Suppose you're trying to solve the equation $f(x)=g(x)$. Then you can find any solutions to $f(x)=g(x)$ that occur amongst values of $x$ for which $g(x)=0$, and then the remaining solutions will be solutions to $\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=1$.

So for example here you have $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cos x$. Whenever $\cos x = 0$ we have $\sin x = 1$ or $-1$, so $\sin x \ne \cos x$ for these values of $x$. Now we can throw away the case $\cos x = 0$ and divide through by $\cos x$.